# how to export a .js file with multiple arrays as module

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I have 2 arrays inside ***data.js*** which looks like this- 
 
[image: I have a data.js file that has 2 arrays like this-]

I have another file ***test.js*** where I want to import ***data.js*** as module like this -

```
const data = require('./data.js')
```

and then access each array in this format-

```
data.girlsDataWeightAge[0]
data.boysDataWeightAge[0]
```

currently I am exporting each array like this -

```
export const NameOfArray= []
```

amd importing each array separately like this-

```
 import {girlsDataWeightAge} from './data.js';
 import {girlsDataWeightAge} from './data.js';
```

but I dont want to import them separately because I am going to pass the data through some functions and need to access it **only** the way I have specified above.

Comment: `import * as data from './data.js';`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you mean, maybe I could be wrong.

You can create an empty array like

```
let storeArray = []
```

, and then use push to push the `girlsDataWeightAge`, `boysDataWeightAge` into it.

Then export that storeArray

Then you can import that storeArray which will contain both of `girlsDataWeightAge`, `boysDataWeightAge` into the function you want,

Comment: above solution by @yousaf is the easiest and works.